# Wrong Application.Documents enumeration

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010

My question is short. Unfortunately my examples need a lot of text.

### Short version

Usually `Application.Documents` works fine if I just have opened some files. But after a while (open/close other files and so on) the returned enumeration is **quite often but not always** wrong! (Even the following simple code example fails then.)

```
Sub test_SaveAllUnsavedDocuments()

    Dim Doc As Object

    For Each Doc In Word.Application.Documents
        Debug.Print Doc.Name
    Next
    Debug.Print "Word.Application.Documents.Count: " & Word.Application.Documents.Count

End Sub
```

As far as I can tell:

- Some file names will be returned twice.
- Sometimes the total number of returned file names is correct, sometimes not.
- If the total number of returned file names is correct: some file names simply are missing.
- This does not happen with all documents. But **if it does**, it is **reproducable**.
- `Application.Documents.Count` always returns the correct number of open files.
- The error stops, if eventually the number of listed file names equals two times the actual number of open files.

(I have reproduced this on another PC without any Add-Ons too. OS version is: Windows 7, 64 bit.)

### Long version

I open some files. Example file names:

> "6-1-spare parts (RSM)-2.22-de-DE.docx"
>   "6-1-spare parts (RSM)-2.22-en-GB.docx"
>   "6-1-spare parts (RSM)-2.22-en-US.docx"

My procedure returns:

> 6-1-spare parts (RSM)-2.22-en-US.docx
>   6-1-spare parts (RSM)-2.22-en-GB.docx
>   6-1-spare parts (RSM)-2.22-de-DE.docx
>   Word.Application.Documents.Count: 3

I open another file ("Test.docx") or create a new document via CTRL+N. My procedure returns:

> Test.docx
>   6-1-spare parts (RSM)-2.22-en-US.docx
>   6-1-spare parts (RSM)-2.22-en-GB.docx
>   6-1-spare parts (RSM)-2.22-de-DE.docx
>   Word.Application.Documents.Count: 4

#### Now the errors start

I close "Test.docx". My procedure returns:

> 6-1-spare parts (RSM)-2.22-en-US.docx
>   6-1-spare parts (RSM)-2.22-en-US.docx
>   6-1-spare parts (RSM)-2.22-en-GB.docx
>   6-1-spare parts (RSM)-2.22-de-DE.docx
>   Word.Application.Documents.Count: 3

There is **one duplicate**!

I repeat this and my procedure returns:

> 6-1-spare parts (RSM)-2.22-en-US.docx
>   6-1-spare parts (RSM)-2.22-en-GB.docx
>   6-1-spare parts (RSM)-2.22-en-US.docx
>   6-1-spare parts (RSM)-2.22-en-GB.docx
>   6-1-spare parts (RSM)-2.22-de-DE.docx
>   Word.Application.Documents.Count: 3

There are **two duplicates**!

I repeat this and my procedure returns:

> 6-1-spare parts (RSM)-2.22-en-US.docx
>   6-1-spare parts (RSM)-2.22-en-GB.docx
>   6-1-spare parts (RSM)-2.22-de-DE.docx
>   6-1-spare parts (RSM)-2.22-en-US.docx
>   6-1-spare parts (RSM)-2.22-en-GB.docx
>   6-1-spare parts (RSM)-2.22-de-DE.docx
>   Word.Application.Documents.Count: 3

There are **three duplicates**! And: **now the number of listed file names equals two times the actual number of open files!**

I repeat this **one more time** and my procedure returns:

> 6-1-spare parts (RSM)-2.22-en-US.docx
>   6-1-spare parts (RSM)-2.22-en-GB.docx
>   6-1-spare parts (RSM)-2.22-de-DE.docx
>   Word.Application.Documents.Count: 3

No matter what I do now, the returned list **is (and remains) correct** until I close and re-open the documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have heard about the For ..Each loop not being reliable, but this is the first time I came across an actual sample. The following code doesn't produce that error.

> Sub test_SaveAllUnsavedDocuments()
>
> ```
> Dim Doc As Object
> Dim i As Integer
>
> For i = 1 To Word.Application.Documents.Count 
>     Debug.Print Documents(i).Name
> Next
> Debug.Print "Word.Application.Documents.Count: " & Word.Application.Documents.Count
> ```
>
> End Sub

At first I tried declaring Doc As Document, but that didn't make a difference.